# Merge Sort c++ 1 parameter - vector

Tags: c++

I need help creating a function to do a merge sort in C++ but I am limited to 1 parameter, a vector. I have started and created the code below, but it is not sorting correctly. If anyone could help me fix this problem I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

```
template <class T>
vector<T> mergeSort(std::vector<T> lst){
if(lst.size() == 1){
    return lst;
}
else{
    int size = lst.size();
    int low = floor(size/2);
    int high = ceil(size/2);

    vector<T> left(lst[0], lst[low]);
    vector<T> right(lst[low], lst[size]);

    mergeSort(left);
    mergeSort(right);
    merge(lst, left, right);

    return lst;
}


}

template <class T>
vector<T> merge(vector<T>list, vector<T> left, vector<T> right){
auto l = left.begin();
auto r = right.begin();
auto a = list.begin();

while(l != left.end() && r != right.end()){
    if(*r < *l){
        *a = *r;
        r++;
    }
    else{
        *a = *l;
        left++;
    }

    a++;

}

return list;
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: Be explicit. That there is a problem is all but implied by the fact that you made a post, so state exactly what the problem is.  Writing a clear problem statement has the side benefit of often shaking loose the solution, eliminating the need for the question. Also include in the question a [mcve] that produces the problem and nothing but the problem. As with the clear problem statement, creating a MCVE often reveals the problem to you in all of its buggy glory making the question unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the function recursively but you dont use the returned values. Here:

```
    mergeSort(left);
    mergeSort(right);
    merge(lst, left, right);

    return lst;
```

it looks as if you assume the call to `mergeSort(left)` would modify `left`, but it does not (the parameter is passed by value, ie a copy is made).

I didnt check it all trough and as this appears to be an exercise I dont want to give you the full solution, but you need something along the line of:

```
    auto sorted_left = mergeSort(left);
    auto sorted_right = mergeSort(right);
    auto sorted = merge(sorted_left, sorted_right);
    return sorted;
```

Also note that this implementation is extremely inefficient (because of recursively creating loads of vectors and passing them by value). Even if this is an exercise, it is a rather poor one. Seems like it is trying to teach you bad practice. You should rather pass iterators around or learn how to work with algorithms (`std::sort` in particular).

Comment: When I do this, it gives me the error that the merge function expects 6 parameters, but i only provided 3 and that they aren't being passed in by reference, but thats not what I want to do.

Comment: @SarahRose when you do what? You probably have to modify more than this 4 lines in your code. The `merge` function as you posted it takes 3 parameters, so I honeslty have no idea what you mean